# Clone or duplicate a task in c#

Tags: c#, task

Because task can not run twice (it would throw an exception). I am creating ahead 2 tasks.
Is there a nice way to duplicate a task instead, something maybe like that:

```
    Task t1 = new Task();
    Task t2 = new Task(t1);
```

Comment: [X Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  You have Problem X, and you think Solution Y will solve it, but you can't make solution Y work, so instead of asking about X, you ask about Y.  **Ask us about X.**

Comment: No, there is no way to clone a task.  Agree about the X/Y problem.

Comment: I have a problem X, then I solve this problem, and I want to run X again. But now, I can't run t1 again, that's why I want to duplicate t1 to t2 and then run t2.

Comment: @LeonardKeret They mean "what exactly are you trying to achieve by cloning a task?".

Comment: When you solve the problem X, you run code to setup and solve it.  To do it a second time, I believe you need to run that code again.  Put the code in a function that returns a task

Comment: Why can't you create the second `Task` like the first one?

Comment: Instead of worrying about cloning tasks, create a task factory that returns these tasks you want to run more than once and run each one once?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is that I can run the code again. Let's say I run something, there is an error, I show it to the user, he fixes it, and then I want to run his last action/task again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you truly need to *clone* a task? If not then one way to achieve the same outcome would be to first create an Action and then create two tasks that take the same Action.

```
var work = new Action(() =>
{
    // do work here
});

var t1 = new Task(work);
var t2 = new Task(work);
```

Comment: I guess the answer to my question is: No, but this is the closest one.

Comment: With the 'method' that needs to call the same task more than once.  Instead of passing in the Task, pass in a function that returns the task, deferring the task creation.  Within the method call this function to create new instances of the task. i.e. DoSomethingWithATask(() => myTargetClass.TaskMethod()).  Inside the method call the func() i.e. await func(); await func().  They will be both different instances of the Task.